# Wordpress, wrong or no posts

Tags: wordpress

Can anybody help with this issueI’ve been battling with for days?
The task I thought should be simple but I’m missing something.

I have a custom post type and each post type is assigned to a child category, I loop through the child categories and call a function each iteration that gets the posts assigned to it, or at least it’s supposed to.

If I remove the cat_idfrom args then all results listed (even though it only gets three at a time (for some strange reason).

If I add the cat_id then no posts get returned, I have checked the posts are correctly assigned to their categories and they are, I have echoed the ID’s to the page to check they’re present and they are but still with a cat in args I get no results.

Here is the categories loop which appears to work fine:

```
$categories = get_categories();
foreach( $categories as $category ) {

        if ( $category->parent > 0 ) {
            $child_cat_ID[] =  $category->term_id;
            $parent_cat_ID = $category->parent;
            $catty = $category->term_id;
            get_geo_services($category->term_id, $category->slug);
        }
    }
```

And here is my function that should be retrieving the posts:

```
function get_geo_services($cat_id, $category_name) {
    echo 'Services in '.$category_name. ' with the cat ID of '.$cat_id;
    $args = array(  
        'post_type' => 'geo_service',
        'cat' => '.$cat_id.',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 20, 
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC');
    
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 
      echo '<div class="row">'; 
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
            echo '<div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">'; 
                echo '<div class="service-card">';
                    echo '<h4 class="service-card-title">'; 
                        echo '<a href="';
                        the_permalink();
                        echo '">';
                            the_title();
                        echo '</a>';
                    echo '</h4>';
                    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                        <div class="service-card_image">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif;
                    echo '<div class="service-card_content">';
                        the_excerpt(); 
                    echo '</div>'; 
                echo '</div>'; 
            echo '</div>'; 
            endwhile;
        echo '</div>';
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
}
```

Can anybody please help, I’m sure someone with WP expertise will be able to spot what I am doing wrong.

I have written this bug/error clearly enough

Thank you in advance.

This is the staging URL with the cat in args commented out, just gets the first three posts eachtime

Comment: In the `args` array, I would try `'cat' => '$cat_id'` instead of `'cat' => '.$cat_id.'` (i.e. without dots - WP is expecting an integer here)

Comment: Thanks, I did try that but it did't make any difference, I also tried ```'cat' => $cat_id, ```

Comment: @BarryPoore did you get the solution?

Comment: Please share custom post type code is there any custom taxonomy if yes then you need to do something else here.

Comment: No Solution yet, I was using the default Wordpress categories, I have just noticed I can add taxonomies in the Custom Post Type  (CPT UI), should I use those instead of the standard Wordpress ones?

Comment: Actually your comment about custom taxonomy has struck a chord, so on the custom post type in the UI, I should uncheck the standard Wordpress categories and create the taxonomy inside CPT UI? And then loop through those instead?

Comment: Just in case the problem hasn't been solved yet: The WordPress Docs for [register_post_type](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#taxonomies) say: *When registering a post type, always register your taxonomies using the **taxonomies** argument.* As Vasim Shaikh requested, we need to see your code that calls the `register_post_type()` function. You may not have connected **category** to the custom post type. The answers to [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7138) may help.